# Post new record with createdAt & updatedAt on Parse platform

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to insert new record with createdAt date provided:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \ 
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: ${MASTER_KEY}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"objectId": "xdH402yd9z", "field": "testData", "createdAt": {"__type": "Date", "iso": "2020-05-23T12:26:17.548Z"}}' $URL
```

Parse Server accepts the request, however it overrides createdAt date with current date.
What am I missing? Is there a server setting or request flag?

I assume the same answer would apply for updatedAt field.

Thank you.

Comment: These fields are automatically handled by Parse Server and there is no way to write on them via the API.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Is there a reason for the restriction?
I mean it is possible to set `objectId` so why not `createdAt` & `updatedAt`?
One use case is export and import of data, in case of backup or data migration.
Perhaps it is not applicable to large datasets, but workable for small datasets.

Comment: Curiously even `back4app.com` import does not preserve `createdAt` & `updatedAt`

Comment: Yes. The only way to write on these fields is via query directly to the database.